# BigQuery SQL - Combine multiple rows from 1 column that match rows from another table?

Tags: sql, join, google-bigquery, string-aggregation

I'm new to Big Query and SQL in general, having really on spent a few days with it so far.
I've spent quite a few hours on my current goal and can't seem to find a way to achieve my objective...
I think I've got the Concat right, but am getting duplicated that I can't get rid off as there's one row for each SPECID.
Also not sure once I get rid of them, how I join in the third table without more duplicates?

**DATA:**

```
t1  
SUMID   Reference   Type    Size
1001    234         Round   120
1002    234         Square  60

t2                      
DETID   SUMID   SPECID  Value
2001    1001    1       TRUE
2002    1001    2       TRUE
2003    1001    3       FALSE
2004    1001    4       TRUE
2005    1001    5       FALSE
2006    1001    6       TRUE
2007    1002    1       FALSE
2008    1002    2       TRUE
2009    1002    3       FALSE
2010    1002    4       TRUE
2011    1002    5       TRUE
2012    1002    6       TRUE

t3          
SPECID  Description     
1       Blue        
2       Red     
3       Green       
4       Orange      
5       Yellow      
6       Purple
```

**OUTPUT**

```
t1.Reference    t1.Type  t1.Size  t3.Description
234             Round     120     Blue, Red, Orange, Purple
234             Square     60     Red, Orange, Yellow, Purple
```

I've made it as far as the following, but for the life of me, I can't get my head around it.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
t1.SUMID, t1.Reference, t1.Type, t1.Size, t2.Description

FROM Table1 t1
LEFT JOIN Table2 t2 ON t1.T2_ID = t2.T2_ID

LEFT JOIN (
SELECT *
FROM ( 
select SUMID, Value,
  CONCAT(
    STRING_AGG(CAST(SPECID AS STRING), ', ') OVER(PARTITION BY SUMID, Value) 
        ) SPEC_IDs

from Table2
)) t2 ON t1.SUMID = t2.SUMID

WHERE t2.Value = TRUE
```

If anyone could break this down for me I'd be really appreciative?
I'm hoping once I see how it works it'll just click.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, this is some `JOIN`s with aggregation:

```
SELECT t1.Reference, t1.Type, t1.Size,
       STRING_AGG(t3.Description, ', ')
FROM Table1 t1 LEFT JOIN
     Table2 t2
     ON t2.T2_ID = t1.T2_ID AND 
        t2.Value LEFT JOIN
     Table3 t3
     ON t3.SPECID = t2.SPECID
GROUP BY t1.Reference, t1.Type, t1.Size;
```

Comment: Wow!
Thanks Gordon, That's soo much less complicated than I was imagining it!